# How to interpret the momentum structure figure of the inelastic neutron scattering data?

Tags: scattering, neutrons

[image: 1]

I am recently reading inelastic neutron scattering papers and I can always see figures like the one above (https://science.sciencemag.org/content/356/6342/1055). However, I couldn't understand what it means, especially don't understand the meaning of $x$ and $y$ axes. Could anyone help me please? Why the $x$ and $y$ axes can be written as $[H,H,0]$ and $[K,-K,0]$?

Comment: you should give a link to the paper that has the figure

Comment: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/356/6342/1055

Comment: Well I undertstand now it is a scattering intensity map on the reciprocal plane. But why the x and y axes are [H,H,0]  and [K,-K,0]?

Comment: no idea, but found another one https://www.nature.com/articles/35023094/figures/1

Comment: https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/28/024/28024530.pdf  , it needs crystallography background, so I cannot help.

Comment: second thoughts, the variables must be related to the spin structure of the lattice

Comment: Yes that is why neutron scattering was used here: to confirm whether there is a magnetic order or not.